# Checkbox in html using php

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I am creating a table in which each cell should have a checkbox.The layout of table is coming fine but in each cell I am getting blank instead of a checkbox like this   http://s28.postimg.org/cssu0w1vx/pic.png.But if I dont use loop and do it manually it shows checkboxes
Below is the php code

```
 <?php
  $j=0;
  for($k=0;$k<3;$k++)
  {
      if($k==0)
      {
          echo "<tr id="."spanDate".">";
          for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)
          {
             if($i==0)
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='time' value='" . ($i+1) . "'></td>";
            else
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='time" . $j . "' value='" . ($i+1) . "'></td>";
            $j++;
          }
          echo "</tr>";
      }
      else
      {
          echo "<tr id="."spanDate".$k.">";
          for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)
          {
             if($i==0)
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='time' value='" . ($i+1) . "'></td>";
            else
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='time" . $j . "' value='" . ($i+1) . "'></td>";
            $j++;
          }
          echo "</tr>";
      }

  }
?>
</table>
```

AFTER running the updated code given by @bs03 I get this

```
  <tr id=spanDate><td><input type='checkbox' name='time' value='1'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time1' value='2'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time2' value='3'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time3' value='4'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time4' value='5'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time5' value='6'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time6' value='7'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time7' value='8'></td></tr><tr id=spanDate1><td><input type='checkbox' name='time' value='1'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time9' value='2'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time10' value='3'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time11' value='4'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time12' value='5'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time13' value='6'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time14' value='7'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time15' value='8'></td></tr><tr id=spanDate2><td><input type='checkbox' name='time' value='1'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time17' value='2'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time18' value='3'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time19' value='4'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time20' value='5'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time21' value='6'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time22' value='7'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='time23' value='8'></td></tr></table>
```

CSS CODE

```
<style>
.CSSTableGenerator {
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    border:1px solid #000000;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
}
.CSSTableGenerator table tr:first-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}
.CSSTableGenerator table tr:first-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:first-child{
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr:hover td{

}
.CSSTableGenerator tr:nth-child(odd){ background-color:#ffaa56; }
.CSSTableGenerator tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:#ffffff; }.CSSTableGenerator td{
    vertical-align:middle;


    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:7px;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000000;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td{
    border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td{
        background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ff7f00 5%, #bf5f00 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ff7f00), color-stop(1, #bf5f00) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ff7f00 5%, #bf5f00 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ff7f00", endColorstr="#bf5f00");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#ff7f00,bf5f00);

    background-color:#ff7f00;
    border:0px solid #000000;
    text-align:center;
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child:hover td{
    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ff7f00 5%, #bf5f00 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ff7f00), color-stop(1, #bf5f00) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ff7f00 5%, #bf5f00 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ff7f00", endColorstr="#bf5f00");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#ff7f00,bf5f00);

    background-color:#ff7f00;
}
.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td:first-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you concatenating them unnecessarily. Only concatenate where needed and add the `'`/`"`s properly.Simply do -

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='time' value='" . ($i+1) . "'></td>";
```

For else part -

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='time" . $j . "' value='" . ($i+1) . "'></td>"
```

Comment: just a few second faster than me

Comment: still no use. I still see blank spaces no checkbox

Comment: Can you check the created html?

Comment: Not this. After running the updated code the source of the page.

Comment: Yes checked I have added the code and it seems fine to me

Comment: It is fine. Have you checked the `css`?